# Blender 2.78: Study materials for learning node editing for materials in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I am new to CGI. I have started learning using Blender.
Where can I learn about each node editor nodes in detail and creating different materials using node editor ?

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/index.html ?

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender

Comment: Try watching Blender Guru, a blender pro, on youtube. He has helped me a lot when it comes to material nodes. He explains each node in detail in his beginner series.. Also look at CG Geek on youtube. Hope i helped :)